# If $f(w)=\max\{|f(w+re^{i\theta})|\}$, what does this say about $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis

The full question is:
Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in a domain $\Omega$ and that $\partial B(w,r)\subset\Omega$. Using Cauchy's Integral Formula, we can deduce
$$f(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(w+re^{i\theta})d\theta.$$

Assuming that $f(w) = \max\{|f(w+re^{i\theta}|\}$, this means

$$f(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \Re f(w+re^{i\theta})d\theta\qquad (\star)\\\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(w+re^{i\theta}|d\theta \\ \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} f(w)d\theta = f(w).$$
What does this say about $f$?

I don't understand the $(\star)$ step. How did they just take the real part of that?
Also, I feel that give $f(w)$ was defined to be the maximum of a modulus, then $f(w)\geq 0$.   Also since $f(w) \geq f(w) \geq 0$ then necessarily, $f(w) = 0$. This seems strange... so if $f(w)$ somehow attained the value that coincided with the maximum of $f(w+re^{i\theta})$, then $f(w+re^{i\theta}) = 0$ necessarily??

Comment: $(\star)$ The real part is not larger than the absolute value: $a\leq \sqrt{a^2}\leq\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Ah! the part before $(\star)$ is because $f(w)$ is real  since it is the maximum of some real numbers.

Comment: @Hellen : Didn't read your comment in full until after I posted. +1 for your observation.

Comment: I see, thanks guys!  
Unsure of what this will say about $f$ though; is my conclusion correct?

Comment: Not from the reasoning you seem to be following. All you can conclude directly is that $f(w)\geq 0$. Your inequalities do not imply that is must equal zero. But I think the Maximum Modulus Principle tells you that the maximum can't occur in the interior of a bounded domain unless the function is constant.

Comment: @MPW I see, thanks! I still don't really see the significance of the lines following $(\star)$. The question had explicitly written that down and asked what it says about $f$ right after.

Comment: I think you want $\overline {B(w,r)} \subset \Omega.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write $f=u+iv.$ From what you have written we can deduce

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi (f(w)-u(w+re^{it}))\, dt = 0.$$

Now observe the integrand is nonnegative and continuous. Thus the only way for this integral to equal $0$ is for the integrand to vanish identically. Therefore $u(w+re^{it}) \equiv f(w).$ From this it follows that $v(w+re^{it})\equiv 0.$

Conclusion: $f$ is the constant $f(w)$ on the circle $\{w+re^{it}\}.$ By the identity principle, $f\equiv f(w)$ in $\Omega.$

Comment: Thank you.   
However, I just noticed that in the second line of the assumption,  
It looks as if we have the inequality:  
$$f(w) \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi  |f(w+re^{i\theta})|\ d\theta \leq f(w).$$  
Wouldn't this mean that $$f(w) \equiv \int_{-\pi}^\pi  |f(w+re^{i\theta})|\ d\theta?$$

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours Sure. But I've just shown $f$ is the constant $f(w)$ everywhere, which is much stronger.

Answer (score 2):

The step ($\star$) is because your assumption states that $f(w)$ is the maximum of a set of real numbers, so it must be real -- and so is equal to the real part of the integral.

**Edit:** Just noticed that this is what @Hellen pointed out in a comment above. Giving credit where credit is due.